# How to efficiently move a unit to a given 2D target position using tank controls?

Tags: movement, control

I am looking for a simple algorithm that can move a unit as fast as possible to a given target position. The unit can only move using the "tank controls": it can turn in both directions and pressing forward moves it in the direction it is facing. The inputs are the position of the unit and the position of the target, the outputs are the direction (left or right) and the movement (forward).

A simple method is to rotate the unit first (so that it faces the target position), and then move it forward. However, this method is slow. It is often faster to rotate AND move at the same time.

In practice, this does not work because the unit can "orbit" the target point, especially when the unit is close to the target.

Here is the pseudo-code I have created so far:

```
vec2 delta = vec2(target.y - unitPos.y, target.x - unitPos.x);

float dist = sqrt(delta.x * delta.x + delta.y * delta.y);
float angle = atan2(delta.y, delta.x);
float diff = angleDiff(angle, unitAngle);
  
if (angle > threshold) direction = -1; 
else if (angle < -threshold) direction = 1;
else direction = 0;

if (dist > threshold) forward = 1;
else forward = 0;
```

I am wondering if there is simple ways to improve this.